# Logo is not aligned left to the Navigation Panel

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager

I'm trying to align the logo to the left side of the navigation panel but it ain't working for some reason. Below is the image showing how it appears:
[image: The Logo have a bit of a space on left side remaining empty.]

But when I removed navigation buttons, the logo appears aligned to the left like this:

[image: Now it's aligned left.]

**Code For Navigation Logo**

```
public class navLogo {

    public void addLogo() {
        try {
            BufferedImage myLogo = ImageIO.read(new File("Images/Logo.png"));
            JLabel logoLabel = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(myLogo));
            new navPanel().getNavPanel().add(logoLabel);
        } catch(IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**Code For Navigation Buttons**

```
public class navBtns {

    private ArrayList<JButton> navBtnList = new ArrayList<>();

    public void setUpNavBtns() {
        makeNavBtns();
        customizeNavBtns();
    }

    void makeNavBtns() {
        navBtnList.add(0, new JButton("Mouse"));
        navBtnList.add(1, new JButton("Visuals"));
        navBtnList.add(2, new JButton("Desktop"));
        navBtnList.add(3, new JButton("Privacy"));
        navBtnList.add(4, new JButton("Encryption"));
        navBtnList.add(5, new JButton("Optimization"));
        navBtnList.add(6, new JButton("Settings"));
    }

    void customizeNavBtns() {
        for (JButton jButton : navBtnList) {
            jButton.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.PLAIN, 20));
            jButton.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
            jButton.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10));
            jButton.setFocusPainted(false);
            jButton.setBorderPainted(false);
            jButton.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
            jButton.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
            jButton.setOpaque(false);

            new navPanel().getNavPanel().add(jButton);
        }
    }
}
```

Good answer will be appreciated. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

After removing the following line from navBtns.java, it works:

```
jButton.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
```